# Does a Nigerian require a visa for sightseeing in Turkey?

Tags: transit-visas, turkey, istanbul, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian citizen and have booked a Turkish Airlines flight to Nigeria with 12 hours both ways (return) layover at Istanbul Airport. I have a Chinese residence permit.

Do I need a transit visa at Istanbul Airport to enter Istanbul for city sightseeing?

Comment: I retracted my close vote because it looks like requirements have changed since that question in 2014. See my answer.

Comment: I did check the link u sent . Yet its complicated. But tanx

Answer (score 4):

You will need to apply for a visa, but it looks like you can apply for an e-visa [here](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).

From the FAQs, they say to check on whether you are eligible by starting a new application. Once you enter your country of citizenship/passport and the type of passport, the site says that a Nigerian citizen on an ordinary passport can get an e-visa.

Comment: So my layover for going is 12 hours and returning is 19 hours.  Both ways I don't visa?  Coz I wanna go into the Istanbul town

Comment: @crazydre.tanx... But I don't have a schengen, USA or uk residence permit.  So I can't fill the supporting document column

Comment: Oops, I didn't go through the for far enough. The requirements still need a visa for a 1st world country, so the duplicate Q&A is still valid. Sorry, @Fez for the confusion.

Comment: Is all good.  I rather go to the embassy here in china

Comment: @Fez Make sure you get two visas, or a double-entry visa